# python syntax err in dictionary across multiple lines

Tags: python, dictionary

With this code:

```
foo = {
    '.0': [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    '.1':[
        {},
        {},
        {
            '.0':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]
            '.1':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I run and get this error:

```
  File "testpy.py", line 17
    '.1':[
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why? How do I format dicts/lists to span multiple lines?

Comment: I miss the "too localized" close reason...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pointing out a one character syntax error

Comment: You should have more patience when debugging :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma:

```
foo = {
    '.0': [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    '.1':[
        {},
        {},
        {
            '.0':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ], # <----- comma needed here
            '.1':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: wow... I don't know how the parser works, but it does seem weird in retrospect to be pointing at the line that it is. EDIT: I was looking at the inccorect '.1' the whole time. oops

Comment: Wow, our answers are nearly identical!

Comment: I think it feels natural that it's pointing at the line which doesn't make sense (since it was expecting something else)

Comment: The parser only knows that there's been an error when it has pulled off the next token, which is `'.1'`

Comment: Yes, you need to read the line number too!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `,` before the second `.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma:

```
foo = {
    '.0': [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ],
    '.1':[
        {},
        {},
        {
            '.0':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ], # <==== Missing comma here
            '.1':[
                {},
                {},
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If your syntax error seems really odd, it's usually because of the previous line.